# Finding rotation matrix "component" around a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, rotations

I am trying to figure out a way to calculate the angle that a vector gets rotated around itself if a rotation matrix is applied to it.

For example if we take a vector $\vec{k} = (0, 0, 1)$ and rotate it $45^{\circ}$ around the Z axis (in this case the vector itself), well end up with the same vector $\vec{k'} = (0, 0, 1)$ but it essentially rotated around Z axis by $45^{\circ}$. What I am interested in calculating is that $45^{\circ}$ angle for more complex rotations around multiple axes and vectors that are not on any particular axis.

If we find a vector that is orthogonal to $\vec{k}$, for example, $\vec{i} = (1, 0, 0)$, and we apply that same rotation to it  we'll end up with a rotated vector $\vec{i'} = (0.707, -0.707, 0)$. In this particular case I could just calculate the angle between $\vec{i}$ and $\vec{i'}$ and get my answer, but if the rotation was around multiple axes and not just Z that would not work.

Is there a way to calculate this rotation matrix "component" (there might be a more appropriate term for this?)? Would it be possible to split the original rotation matrix into 2 parts - rotation matrix that only has elements which directly affect the output vector, and an angle that the vector gets rotated around its own axis?

Edit 1: An example of a more complicated rotation matrix

If we have a vector
$\vec{v} = (0, 0, 1)$, an orthogonal vector $\vec{x} = (0.707, 0.707, 0)$ and a rotation matrix:

```
M = 
 0.500   0.707  -0.500
-0.500   0.707   0.500
 0.707   0.000   0.707
```

If we apply the rotation matrix to $\vec{x}$ we get $\vec{Mx} = (0.854, 0.146, 0.5)$.

If we then plot those vectors and view directly into a plane that $\vec{v}$ is normal of (in this case XY plane but can be any 2D plane), what I would like to know is the angle that I need to rotate $\vec{x}$ around $\vec{v}$ by to have it overlap with $\vec{Mx}$ in that view.

In this case the answer is around $35.2^\circ$ (manual try and error)

Note: $\vec{v}$ is usually not on one of the coordinate axes, this is just easier explain with (I think). Another example could be $\vec{v} = (0.424, 0.566, 0.707)$

[Visual example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNpX2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say non-zero $v \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$ defines the line we rotate around by matrix $M$. Pick arbitrary non-zero $x \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$ with $\| x \| = 1$ and $\langle x, v \rangle = 0$. Now $Mx$ is the rotated vector and $\| Mx \| = 1$ as well, also $\langle Mx, v \rangle = 0$. Now compute $\| x - Mx \|$.

So you have a triangle with two sides equal to 1 and one side equal to $\| x - Mx \|$. That should be enough info to calculate the angle.

You are allowed to skip the condition $\| x \| = 1$ btw. Note $Mv = v$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. It would work fine for the case when rotation happens around `v` (or as you note `Mv = v`), which is like the example in the question. However I am trying to solve for when rotation happens around any axis that is not necessarily `v`, for which case this does not work anymore

Comment: What you mean by ‘any axis’?

Comment: This works for any non-zero $v$.

Comment: Hi @Elmex80s, I have added a more complex example and a visualisation of vectors and which angle I am trying to find. Also, by 'any axis', I mean that rotation matrix could contain rotations around a combination of individual rotations around `X`, `Y` and `Z` axes and the overall rotation is not happening around `v` but some arbitrary axis.

Comment: $v$ doesn’t seem to play any role here. It only is about $M$, am I right?

Comment: Well `M` is a 3x3 rotation matrix which gets applied to `v`. In effect I am trying to find out how much the vector to which it is applied gets rotated around itselft. I.e. as in my first example if avector is along Z -  `(0,0, 1)`, and we rotate it by 45 degrees around only Z axis, we get the same output vector, but in effect it got rotated by itself by all that amount. I am trying to solvo for that but in more complicated cases where the vector and rotation matrix can be of any real value.

Comment: If for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$ holds $\|Mx\| = \|x\|$ then the "Angle of interest (in this 2D view)" can be found by my solution.

Comment: Well if I go through the example in the edit 1 with $\vec{v} = (0, 0, 1)$ and $\vec{x} = (0.707, 0.707, 0)$ ($\|x\| = 1$). If we apply the rotation matrix we get $\vec{Mx} = (0.8535, 0.146, 0.5)$ and $\|Mx\| = 1$. However, $\langle\vec{Mx},\vec{v}\rangle = 0.5 \neq 0$. Furthermore, if we apply $M$ to $\vec{v}$ we get $\vec{Mv} = (-0.5, 0.5, 0.707) \neq \vec{v}$. If we continue with that we get $\vec{x}-\vec{Mx} = (-0.146, 0.561, -0.5)$ and $\|x-Mx\| = 0.765$. Using 3 triangle sides of lengths $1.0$,  $1.0$ and  $0.765$ we find the angle to be $45^\circ$ which is not even close to $35.2^\circ$.

Comment: I believe your solution is basically the same as just using $\cos{\alpha} = \langle x, Mx \rangle / (\|x\| \times \|Mx\|)$ which also gives $\alpha = 45^\circ$. Unless I completely misunderstand your solution (in which case I would really appreciate a more detailed explanation or working through the numbers) I do not see how this solves my problem. Thanks, Titas

Comment: You need to apply a projection on the plane defined by $v$. In that case I got $35.2 ^{\circ}$ as well. So project $x$ and $Mx$ and next step calculate lengths of triangle and find the angle.

Comment: Thanks @elmex80s, that worked :)